# Scala sbt -D environemt variable not found

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to access an environment  variable in my sbt build file.
As told I set the environment variable with the jvm -D Option

```
sbt -DaccessToken=***** compile
```

but scala cannot find the variable

```
 sys.env.get("accessToken").getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("System variable 'accessToken' with the credentials is not set."))
```

Why does the -D option have no effect?
If I set the variable with *export* in linux everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you pass as `-D` is not environment variable and cannot be read as `sys.env.get`.

You need to use Java API to read them

```
System.getProperty("accessToken")
```

Other option is to assign an environment variable before you launch your sbt. In bash, for example, it can be done like this but this, of course, depends on your environment.

```
accessToken=***** sbt compile
```